# find the closure of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis

find the   closure of the following subsets   of $\mathbb{R}  $

$1.  $$( -1,0) \cup \mathbb{N}$

$2.$ $\mathbb{Z}$

My attempt :  for  $1.) $ $[-1,0] \cup \mathbb{R}$

For  $2$ .)  $\bar{ \mathbb{Z}}= \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $[-1,0]\cup\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$. The closure of $A\cup B$ is not always $\bar A\cup\bar B$. And definitely, the closure of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ is not $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @ajotatxe The closure of $A\cup B$ is always $\overline A\cup\overline B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the closure of a set is smallest closed set containing that set, so

$\overline{(-1, 0) \cup \mathbb{N}} = [-1, 0] \cup \mathbb{N}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}= \mathbb{Z}$